# How can I create a time variable with Stata or Excel?

Tags: excel, database-design, statistics, stata

I have a dataset that I am editing so it can be used for a time series regression since the time is not currently in a format that is usable. The format of the existing data is as follows:

```
     --------------------------------------------------
    | id|size |2017price|2016price|2015price|2014price| ...
      -------------------------------------------------
    | 1 | 3   | 50      | 80      |  21     |  56     | ...
     --------------------------------------------------
    | 2 | 5   | 78      | 85      |  54     |  67     | ... 
     --------------------------------------------------
    | 3 | 2   | 18      | 22      |  34     |  54     | ... 
     --------------------------------------------------
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

I would like to add a time variable that accounts for each year and gives the corresponding value as a price variable;

```
    ---------------------------
    | id  | size  |t   | price| 
     --------------------------
    | 1   | 3     |2017| 50   | 
     --------------------------
    | 1   | 3     |2016| 80   |  
     --------------------------
    | 1   | 3     |2015| 21   | 
     --------------------------
    | 1   | 3     |2014| 21   | 
     --------------------------
    | 2   | 5     |2017| 78   | 
     --------------------------
    | 2   | 5     |2016| 85   |  
     --------------------------
    | 2   | 5     |2015| 54   | 
     --------------------------
    | 2   | 5     |2014| 67   | 
     --------------------------
    | 3   | 2     |2017| 18   | 
     --------------------------
    | 3   | 2     |2016| 22   |  
     --------------------------
    | 3   | 2     |2015| 34   | 
     --------------------------
    | 3   | 2     |2014| 54   | 
     --------------------------
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

Is there a function in Stata or Excel that can do this automatically? I have data for 20 years with over 35,000 entries so manually editing won't work.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @pnuts but I couldn't get that to work right but the other answer worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data example as given is not quite suitable as Stata data as variable names cannot begin with numeric characters.

That fixed, this is an exercise for the `reshape` command (not function).

```
clear
input id size price2017 price2016 price2015 price2014 
 1 3 50 80 21 56 
 2 5 78 85 54 67 
 3 2 18 22 34 54 
end 

reshape long price, i(id size) j(year) 
sort id size year 

list , sepby(id)

     +--------------------------+
     | id   size   year   price |
     |--------------------------|
  1. |  1      3   2014      56 |
  2. |  1      3   2015      21 |
  3. |  1      3   2016      80 |
  4. |  1      3   2017      50 |
     |--------------------------|
  5. |  2      5   2014      67 |
  6. |  2      5   2015      54 |
  7. |  2      5   2016      85 |
  8. |  2      5   2017      78 |
     |--------------------------|
  9. |  3      2   2014      54 |
 10. |  3      2   2015      34 |
 11. |  3      2   2016      22 |
 12. |  3      2   2017      18 |
     +--------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, @Nick Cox!